# Django DRF serializers.BooleanField receive False by default but NEED None

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I wonder why i always receive by default False instead of None. I true to use BolleanField, NullBooleanField (same result)

serializer:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    test = serializers.BooleanField(allow_null=True, required=False)
```

View

```
class TestSerializer(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):
       data = TestSerializer(data=request.data)
       data.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
       print(data)
```

when I send post request via Postman w/o passing `test` in body i expect to receive in my print statement `{'test': None}` but instead I receive `{'test': False}`

as far as I understood it is default expected behavior of Django (I read this issue: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/3811)

But I wonder how can I make it None instead of False?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to set `default=None` ?

Comment: @berkeeb if use default it automatically mark field as reuired=True

Comment: `field = serializers.BooleanField(allow_null=True, default=None, required=False)` actually worked for a class that inherit `rest_framework.serializers.Serializer`.  `data={}` `serializer = ExampleSerialzer(data=data)` after checking validtion the validated data equals to `data = {"field": None}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django REST Framework a boolean/None value in the request is getting set to False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025802/django-rest-framework-a-boolean-none-value-in-the-request-is-getting-set-to-fals)

Answer (score 0):

When using HTML encoded form input be aware that omitting a value will always be treated as setting a field to `False`, even if it has a `default=True`

[here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#booleanfield)

so, should use:

> test = serializers.BooleanField(allow_null=True, default=None)

as commented above